# Scroll in chrome for mobile not working

Tags: android, google-chrome, mobile, scroll, touch-event

[Link to the Page that does not work](http://www.nordseeduggen.de/nordseeduggen2013)

Hello Community,

On this page scrolling with safari on an Iphone 5 just works a charm. But on my HTC with Chrome 31.0.1700.99 and Android 4.1.1 I can only scroll if I touch the screen with two fingers. The scrolling than is still very slowly. I tried to analyse the problem using adb and remote debugging but I am really new to everything mobile.

It seems as if there would be no touchstart and touchend event but I dunno if it is not fired or if I need to handle those events manually and they ain't handled.

Just telling me this would be a big help. Thanks a lot for your efforts.